# Django 1.7.4: messages not showing up in TemplateView

Tags: django

I'm trying to add messages to a first view and pass them to a second view with a redirect:

First view:

```
def index(request):
    ...etc...
    messages.info(request, "My message!")
    return redirect('second_view', pk=pk)
```

Second view:

```
class SecondView(TemplateView):                                                       

template_name = "template.html"                                                     

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                           
    context = super(SecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)                  
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')                                                                                                
    context.update({                                                            
        'pk': pk,                                                                                                               
    })                                                                          
    return context                                                              

@method_decorator(login_required)                                               
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)                                           
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                                            
    return super(SecondView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

`template.html`:

```
{% if messages %}                                                                                                        
<div>                                                                                                                    
    <p>This is a test.</p>                                                                                               
    {% for message in messages %}                                                                                        
        {{message}}                                                                                                      
    {% endfor %}                                                                                                         
</div>                                                                                                                   
{% endif %}
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (                                                     
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                                  
    'django.core.context_processors.request',                                       
    'accounts.context_processors.extra_context',                                    
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',                          
)  

INSTALLED_APPS = (                                                                  
    'django.contrib.admin',                                                         
    'django.contrib.auth',                                                          
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                                  
    'django.contrib.sessions',                                                      
    'django.contrib.messages',                                                      
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',     
    .....etc.....

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (                                                           
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',                      
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',                      
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                                 
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',                                 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',                   
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',            
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',                    
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',                                     
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                                 
)
```

But in my template.html, `{% if messages %}` returns false. How can I get these messages to show up?

EDIT:

If I simply try to put `{{messages}}` into my template, it renders like this: `<django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x108271950>`

but when I call `{% if messages %}` this does not return the contents of the `{%if%}` statement.

EDIT2:

I have a test in which the message appears properly in the html, which passes:

```
  def test_home_page_signup_messages(self):                                       
      data = create_signup_post_data()                                            
      url = reverse('signup')                                                     
      response = self.client.post(url, data, follow=True)                         
      messages = [m.message for m in list(response.context['messages'])]          
      self.assertIn("My message!", messages)  # PASSES
      self.assertIn("My message!", response.content)  # PASSES
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the issue here is that the redirect does not pass any context, which would contain the message. The [documentation explains that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages):

> If you’re using the context processor, your template should be
> rendered with a RequestContext. Otherwise, ensure messages is
> available to the template context.

Thus, `messages` will not available after a redirect. However, you can retrieve messages yourself with [`django.contrib.messages.get_messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages):

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

class SecondView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "template.html"                                                     

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                           
        context = super(SecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)                  
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')                                                                                                
        context.update({                                                            
            'pk': pk,
            'messages': get_messages(self.request),                                                                                                               
        })                                                                          
        return context                                                              

    @method_decorator(login_required)                                               
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)                                           
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                                            
        return super(SecondView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

In response to:

> EDIT:
>
> If I simply try to put `{{messages}}` into my template, it renders like this: `<django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x108271950>`
>
> but when I call `{% if messages %}` this does not return the contents of the `{%if%}` statement.

This is my exact code, less the URLs:

```
# ------- URLS
# Django
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import SecondView

urlpatterns = patterns("myapp.views",
    url(r'^test/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^test/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', view=SecondView.as_view(), name='second_view')
)

# ------- VIEWS

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
def index(request):
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    messages.info(request, "My message!")
    pk = 2
    return redirect('second_view', pk=pk)

from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class SecondView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SecondView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        context.update({
            'pk': pk,
            'messages': get_messages(self.request),
        })
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SecondView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

# ------- TEMPLATE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
                    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
                    {{ message }}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael_B I tried this - see my updated EDIT above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @YPCrumble I just tested locally. It works for me. Simply doing `{{ messages }}` does not work. You have to loop through the messages: `{% for message in messages %}<p>{{ message }}</p>{% endfor %}`

Comment: @YPCrumble - I updated my answer above to show you the exact test code I used.

Comment: @Michael_B it seems my error is that my messages aren't saving. When I put this line into the `get_context_data` function:

`print [m.message for m in list(context['messages'])]` it returns `[]`. Still not sure why this is the case though. This would be just under the `context.update` call.

Comment: Also, the same line works before the redirect, i.e., I can print the messages right before the redirect in the `first_view` view.

Comment: Is there a possibility that there is conflicting context processors? Is the order shown in the original post for the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES what you have? SessionMiddleware has to come before MessageMiddleware. Maybe start commenting out custom middleware/context processors and see if that is it?

Comment: All in all, what I can say is that something in your settings is out of the ordinary. If this is working on my project in Django 1.7.4, there is a deeper issue. Something somewhere is conflicting, which could include the session storage backend, etc.

Comment: @Michael_B - thanks - I believe you're correct. Currently going through the order of my middleware as I imagine that's where the error is.

Comment: @Michael_B I've written a test that runs fine - the problem is the {% if messages %} doesn't fire in the browser. Any idea why this could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right import? Which django version are you using? This works for me on v1.7.4:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,"My message!")
```

Download my project to see the order of middleware you would need:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo601h7xjlk0ztu/project_for_messages.tgz?dl=0

Created from here https://github.com/jpadilla/django-project-template

Comment: I'm importing in the same way. I tried adjusting the call to messages but same result. I'm on 1.7.4.

Comment: Your issue is definitely in the settings. My advice is to create a new project from a template, then add in your views from there.

Comment: I've written a test that runs fine - the problem is the {% if messages %} doesn't fire in the browser. Any idea why this could be happening? Thanks!